# Database insertion error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The below echo statement,

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES(" . $_GET['username'] . "," . $_GET['password'] . "," . $_GET['PasswordHintQuestion'] . "," . $_GET['PasswordHintAnswer'] . "," . $_GET['firstname'] . "," . $_GET['lastname'] . "," . $_GET['genderSelect'] . "," . $_GET['date_in_format'] . "," . $_GET['nationality'] . "," . $_GET['refEmail'] . ")" ;   
echo $statement;
```

gave the ouput as,

```
INSERT INTO ge_user_table VALUES([object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object NodeList],[object HTMLSelectElement]/[object HTMLSelectElement]/[object HTMLSelectElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement])Database Insertion fault on registration
```

But during insertion into database I got the error as,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement],[object
>   HTMLInputElement],[o' at line 1

But, the below query is working fine.

```
INSERT INTO ge_user_table VALUES('Muthu2','1234','Who are you?','Iam Indian','Muthu','Ganapathy','MALE','1991-12-21','Indian','abc@abc.com');
```

**EDIT :**
I have changed the code to,

```
  $username     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
  $password     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['password']);
  $hintQues     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['PasswordHintQuestion']);
  $hintAns      = mysql_escape_string($_GET['PasswordHintAnswer']);
  $firstname    = mysql_escape_string($_GET['firstname']);
  $hintQues     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['lastname']);
  $gender       = mysql_escape_string($_GET['genderSelect']);
  $date         = mysql_escape_string($_GET['date_in_format']) ;
  $nationality  = mysql_escape_string($_GET['nationality']) ;
  $email        = mysql_escape_string($_GET['refEmail']) ;



    $statement = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('$username' ,'$password','$hintQues' ,'$hintAns','$firstname' ,'$lastname' ,".
               "'$gender' ,'$date','$nationality','$email')" ;
```

But,the database has entry as,
[image]

Final Solution:
   I have passed form.username in html instead of form.username.value. Now Got it correct.

Comment: Surprise, strings in SQL must be quoted.

Comment: you need to learn basic SQL syntax. String literal formatting in particular. strings in SQL must be quoted **and escaped.**

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2):

It look like you have error in javascript. you send html DOM Node instead of value.

Also you should escape your get variables like

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
```

Comment: +1 as this is another error, in addition to SQL (mis)formatting

Comment: not whatever "get variables" but "SQL strings".

Comment: @Your Common Sense  see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
  $username     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
  $password     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['password']);
  $hintQues     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['PasswordHintQuestion']);
  $hintAns      = mysql_escape_string($_GET['PasswordHintAnswer']);
  $firstname    = mysql_escape_string($_GET['firstname']);
  $hintQues     = mysql_escape_string($_GET['lastname']);
  $gender       = mysql_escape_string($_GET['genderSelect']);
  $date         = mysql_escape_string($_GET['date_in_format']) ;
  $nationality  = mysql_escape_string($_GET['nationality']) ;
  $email        = mysql_escape_string($_GET['refEmail']) ;



  $statement = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('$username' ,'$password','$hintQues' ,'$hintAns','$firstname' ,'$lastname' ,".
               "'$gender' ,'$date','$nationality','$email')" ;   

  echo $statement;
```

Always try to keep the statement as readable as possible .. also whenever string needs to be inserted .. it should be propery quoted  Also always use mysql_escape_string() to avoid sql injection.

- Possible problem can be ..you are passing html element itself instead of its value

Comment: Why only 2 fields formatted?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh sorry my mistake ... I am just editing it

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT ok post me the html code for the element which your are accessing as $_GET['username']

Comment: @new_developer k. it is like, the mistake is on another file. rectifying it. thank you.

Comment: @new_developer The problem is with me. I have passed form.username instead of form.username.value. sorry, Thank_you.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT  Ok it happens often.. no problem

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT I think you should edit your question back

Answer (score 0):

Your sql syntax is wrong you can use mysql_real_escape_string but you also need to care about how you are passing values to sql.

In above query you symply passed text without quotes.

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES('".$_GET['username']."', '".$_GET['password']."', '".$_GET['PasswordHintQuestion']."', '".$_GET['PasswordHintAnswer']."', '".$_GET['firstname']."', '".$_GET['lastname']."', '".$_GET['genderSelect']."', '".$_GET['date_in_format']."', '".$_GET['nationality']."', '".$_GET['refEmail']."')" ;
```